# Apache access logs for django app with mod-wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I try to serve my Django application with Apache-mod_wsgi in my local computer whose OS is Windows 7.

I have placed my django.wsgi file into proper place and change httpd.conf such that `WSGIScriptAlias / C:\DjangoProjects\tryserver\Apache\django.wsgi` .

However, when I try to reach `http://127.0.0.1`, encountered `You don't have permission to access / on this server.` message.

I have looked at my `access.log` and I have found these two lines

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2011:22:36:50 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2011:22:37:50 +0300] "\x16\x03" 302 222
```

What is the meaning of these logs and how can I resolve them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these lines to `httpd.conf` resolved my problem.

```
<Directory C:/DjangoProjects/tryserver/Apache>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Note have edited this because you should be more specific in your case as WSGI script file was in a sub directory. Being more specific makes your Apache more secure. You don't want to be saying to Apache that it can serve files from the directory with your settings file in it as a stuff up in URL mappings in Apache might then make your code downloadable.